# Unfitting Autocomplete Suggestions in GCSE

Tags: html, google-programmable-search-engine

So, I'm experiencing some issues with the autocomplete feature in Google Custom Search Engine (GCSE). I'll get straight to the point.

1. Why does it seem that most of the autocomplete suggestions that appear underneath the search box contain some Asian characters? I live in the US, and don't really want all of the autocompletions to look foreign. People are going to think my app is from some kind of Asian company. Not only that, but my search engine is set to search the entire web, not a bunch of Asian websites. Restricting the autocomplete language (by applying the HTML attribute data-autoCompleteValidLanguages="en" to my GCSE search box div) fixes nothing. And, I don't really want to restrict the autocompletions to just English anyway.
2. Relating back to problem number one, if I enable "Include autocompletions from the entire web" in the GCSE control panel, the autocompletions are more relevant. But, doing this arises another issue. The list of autocompletions is much too long. According to the GCSE documentation, I should be able to remedy this by adding the following attribute to my GCSE search box div:

   data-autoCompleteMaxCompletions="10"

   But, this doesn't seem to apply when I have "Include autocompletions from the entire web" enabled. I have absolutely no idea why this is. The only thing that could be the case is that enabling "Include autocompletions from the entire web" just adds extra autocompletions to the already existing list of autocomplete suggestions. This is kind of frustrating though, as there's no reason I shouldn't be able to limit the amount of extra autocompletions.

If there is any assistance anyone can give me, it will be very much appreciated. Thank you in advance.